# small misunderstanding of example in msdn related to virtual/override

Tags: c#, overriding

While reading [about polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx) in MSDN, 
I saw an example of virtual and overridden methods:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void DoWork() { }
    public virtual int WorkProperty
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void DoWork() { }
    public override int WorkProperty
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }
}

DerivedClass B = new DerivedClass();
B.DoWork();  // Calls the new method.

BaseClass A = (BaseClass)B;
A.DoWork();  // Also calls the new method.
```

What I want to know is, in what scenario should someone do this?
I just can't see how it is useful in any way. Could someone please give a real-world example?

Comment: `BaseClass` and `DerivedClass` (as one can tell) are not meant to represent a real-world example.

Comment: @haim770 I think OP's point is that he would like a real world example... haha

Comment: @haim770 I know it is an example , but most of the time examples should relate to a REAL scenario that it should be used or in opposite should never used

Comment: @eddie_cat, "I just can see how it is useful in any way". Anyway, simple Google search yield lots of real world examples.

Comment: Whenever you have a base class with a method or property that is the same for most derived classes except for some odd ones. `public class Dog { public virtual string Bark() { return "woof"; } } public class OddDog : Dog { public override string Bark() { return "meow"; } }`

Comment: @haim770 you are right (about the misspelling  ) :) , now corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is useful whenever you want a reference to some objects, and you can't keep references of their exact type. If you for example have a list of objects that are of mixed types:

```
List<BaseClass> list = new List<BaseClass>() {
  new BaseClass(),
  new DerivedClass(),
  new BaseClass(),
  new BaseClass(),
  new DerivedClass(),
  new DerivedClass()
};
```

Now you have a list of `BaseClass` references, but some of them point to `DerivedClass` instances.

When you want to use them, you don't need to check their type. You can just call the virtual `DoWork` method, and the `BaseClass.DoWork` method will be called for the `BaseClass` instanced and the `DerivedClass.DoWork` method will be called for the `DerivedClass` instances:

```
foreach (BaseClass b in list) {
  b.DoWork();
}
```

Comment: Yes, +1, but this could also be done via `abstract` methods or an `interface`. The difference is, with an `abstract` or `interface`, each deriving class *must* provide its own implementation, while with `virtual` the class *can* override if it's not happy with the base implementation, but doesn't *have* to.

Comment: I'm sorry , I don't follow 
tell me if I'm right 
by doing the foreach thingy over the list what is actually happening is that I'm casting each item to BaseClass type than firing DoWork ??
thus I don't need to "know" about the derived children  ?

Comment: @LordTitiKaka - no, those object already *are* `BaseClass`, because they *are* of a type that derives from `BaseClass` (or is `BaseClass` itself). If an object is directly of type `BaseClass`, then calling `DoWork()` will execute the `DoWork()` in `BaseClass`. If the object is of a type derived from `BaseClass` and that type overrides the `DoWork()` method, then that overriden method will be called, even if the object is in a `List<BaseObject>`.

Comment: @Corak: Another neat thing you can do is provide an extension method on an interface. That will not only (effectively) add it to the interface, but provide a default implementation. `IEnumerable` has a ton of those. The bad thing is, there is no `virtual` for those methods.

Answer (score 2):

All you care about is that a `Dancer` can dance. If you're holding a reference to a `Dancer`, then you shouldn't care how that dancer dances--only that they do. This is the idea behind interfaces as well.

So, you throw a party with a dance floor, and you want people to dance. But let them be themselves, dance the way they want to, and have a good time.

```
List<Dancer> danceFloor = new List<Dancer>();
danceFloor.Add(new ReservedDancer());
danceFloor.Add(new SuperFreakDancer ());

public class Dancer
{
    public virtual void DoYourDance()
    {
        // do the robot. Everyone knows that one right?
    }
}

public class ReservedDancer : Dancer
{
    public override void DoYourDance()
    {
        // do the waltz
    }
}

public class SuperFreakDancer : Dancer
{
    public override void DoYourDance()
    {
        // breakdance !!!
    }
}
```

As for why you might use polymorphic assignment in the same function, consider a `Dancer` factory method (you could add this to the `Dancer` class, and let `DancerType` be an enumeration that describes each dancer type):

```
public static Dancer NewDancerFromType(DancerType type)
{
    Dancer ret = null;
    switch (type)
    {
        case DancerType.Reserved:
            ret = new ReservedDancer();
            break;
        case DancerType.SuperFreak:
            ret = new SuperFreakDancer();
            break;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Sometimes, also, let's say that `Dancer` is `public`, but its subclasses were `private`. That way you could use this factory method to get instances of those subclasses, but you would still be holding `Dancer` references. I have implemented that pattern several times for practical purposes, and I can tell you about that but it's long and starts to get off the topic of this thread.

Comment: 1) great answer(of course I know the robot dance) !
2) what I dont get is the casting they did there and it's porpuse

Comment: So they can both a) Demonstrate polymorphism and b) do it in one section of code. Ok, you wouldn't do it *exactly* like they just did, probably, but there is one case you might in the same function. I'm going to add an edit for this case.

Comment: `BaseClass A` means, that `A` is a container that can hold any object of type `BaseClass` or any object of any type that derives from `BaseClass`. The cast in `BaseClass A = (BaseClass)B` is unnecessary and is simply there to point out that even then the `DoWork()` from the `DerivedClass` will be called.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem with most of the teaching/literature related to object-oriented programming and polymorphism is that there is a great lack of actual useful real-world examples, maybe because they are too complex. Having said that, here is yet another crappy example :)

Basically, any polymorphic code can be rewritten as an if-else statement. Consider the following code:

```
class Car {
    public virtual void Drive() {
        Console.WriteLine("Driving like a normal car");
    }
}

class RaceCar : Car { 
    public override void Drive() { 
        Console.WriteLine("Driving really fast!");
    }
}
```

Now, in a prehistoric (pre-OO) time we would have some code somewhere to say if we have a racecar:

```
if (isRaceCar) {
        Console.WriteLine("Driving really fast!");
} else {
        Console.WriteLine("Driving like a normal car");
}
```

So, why would we create this whole class structure, the second piece of code seems a lot simpler.

Let's say we added a third car type:

```
class OldCar : Car {
     public override void Drive() { 
         Console.WriteLine("Driving very slowly");
     }
}
```

Now, our boolean system will not work anymore, so we need to have a switch or something

```
switch (carType) {

    case RaceCar: ... 
    case OldCar: ...
    case Car: ...
}
```

Allright, seems ok. But now we also want our car to do other stuff besides drive, e.g. `GetIn`, `GetOut`, `Stop`, `DoMaintenance`, etc etc. And real world examples can be much much bigger.

Without polymorphism this will result in our car-related code being scattered all over the place, and it is very easy to forget a switch case somewhere if you add a new type of car. Using polymorphism, especially using abstract methods and interfaces, forgetting one of these cases will cause a **compiler error** instead of a **runtime error** or **hidden bug**, because we are forced to implement the appropriate method.

It is important to note that these if/else or switch cases still exist when using polymorphism, but all the hard work is done by the compiler itself, and we don't have to think about it much.

This is just a single example, there are other benefits such as:

- Being able to extend the code without changing the original (e.g. someone else creating their own `Car` and sending it to some other code that does stuff with cars). This means you are reusing code that handles cars when adding a new type of car.
- Allowing small variations of the same behavior (e.g. I want a normal car but I only want it to display an extra message when someone drives it).